# app widget click doesnt work when app killed

Tags: android, widget, mouseclick-event

I have a widget and it works well when the app is running in the background. But when I kill the app with application manager, the widget doesn't fire the click event. Then I re-open the app, and the widget still doesn't fire the click event. Any ideas?

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private ArrayList<Widget> widgets;
    private static String listing1 = "";
    private static String listing2 = "";
    private static String listing3 = "";
    private static String listing4 = "";
    private static String listing5 = "";
    RemoteViews views;

    public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.i("ExampleWidget", "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("islem", "recommendation");

        ServiceConnector.secretcvAPI.getWidgetItems(params, new SuccessCallback<GetWidgetResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(GetWidgetResponse getWidgetResponse, Response response) {
                widgets = getWidgetResponse.widgets;

                for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

                    listing1 = widgets.get(0).ilan_id;
                    listing2 = widgets.get(1).ilan_id;
                    listing3 =  widgets.get(2).ilan_id;
                    listing4 = widgets.get(3).ilan_id;
                    listing5 = widgets.get(4).ilan_id;
                    // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
                    // to the button
                    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listing1, getPendingSelfIntent(context, widgets.get(0).ilan_id, appWidgetId));
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listing2, getPendingSelfIntent(context, widgets.get(1).ilan_id, appWidgetId));
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listing3, getPendingSelfIntent(context, widgets.get(2).ilan_id, appWidgetId));
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listing4, getPendingSelfIntent(context, widgets.get(3).ilan_id, appWidgetId));
                    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listing5, getPendingSelfIntent(context, widgets.get(4).ilan_id, appWidgetId));

                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listingNameTV, widgets.get(0).firma.isim);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listingNameTV2, widgets.get(1).firma.isim);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listingNameTV3, widgets.get(2).firma.isim);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listingNameTV4, widgets.get(3).firma.isim);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.listingNameTV5, widgets.get(4).firma.isim);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.positionNameTV, widgets.get(0).ilan_baslik);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.positionNameTV2, widgets.get(1).ilan_baslik);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.positionNameTV3, widgets.get(2).ilan_baslik);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.positionNameTV4, widgets.get(3).ilan_baslik);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.positionNameTV5, widgets.get(4).ilan_baslik);

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("http:" + widgets.get(0).firma.logo)
                            .into(views, R.id.widgetIV, new int[]{appWidgetId});

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("http:" + widgets.get(1).firma.logo)
                            .into(views, R.id.widgetIV2, new int[]{appWidgetId});

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("http:" + widgets.get(2).firma.logo)
                            .into(views, R.id.widgetIV3, new int[]{appWidgetId});

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("http:" + widgets.get(3).firma.logo)
                            .into(views, R.id.widgetIV4, new int[]{appWidgetId});

                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load("http:" + widgets.get(4).firma.logo)
                            .into(views, R.id.widgetIV5, new int[]{appWidgetId});

                    // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
                    // widget
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, int appWidgetId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (listing1.equals(intent.getAction())){
            startApplciationWithIntent(context, listing1);
        }

        else if (listing2.equals(intent.getAction())){
            startApplciationWithIntent(context, listing2);
        }

        else if (listing3.equals(intent.getAction())){
            startApplciationWithIntent(context, listing3);
        }

        else if (listing4.equals(intent.getAction())){
            startApplciationWithIntent(context, listing4);
        }

        else if (listing5.equals(intent.getAction())){
            startApplciationWithIntent(context, listing5);
        }
    }

    private void startApplciationWithIntent(Context context, String ilanid){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoggedOutActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("DeepLink", ilanid);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<!-- Widget-->
    <receiver android:name=".Widget" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: i still dont have a solution for this, any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking for a solution to this as well, and hopefully this will help a bit:

If you checkout soundcloud's widget you can notice that when the app is killed,

1. the widget has no layout to indicate an 'off' state
2. you click on it, it first starts the app, which updates the widget's layout and buttons
3. you click again to play your music.

So, I'm thinking, you should have a service running which will first start your app when the user clicks the widget.